# How To Set Up nginx Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, dns, host, vhosts

Problem: Unwanted nginx vhost redirection to www.domain.com

1. I configured my server/dns as follows:

root@letthemstare:~# cat /etc/hostname
letthemstare

```
root@letthemstare:~# cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 letthemstare.dev.local letthemstare

#Virtual Hosts 
178.62.111.20    letthemstare.com 

root@letthemstare:~# head -20 /etc/nginx/sites-available/letthemstare.com 
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.letthemstare.com letthemstare.com 178.62.111.20;
    root /var/www/lts/public_html;

    ## rewrite example.com to www.example.com
     if ($http_host != "letthemstare.com") {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://letthemstare.com$request_uri permanent;
     }
```

sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/letthemstare.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/letthemstare.com

```
Kfirs-MacBook-Pro:~ silis$ ping letthemstare.com
PING letthemstare.com (178.62.111.20): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 178.62.111.20: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=147.152 ms

Kfirs-MacBook-Pro:~ silis$ ping www.letthemstare.com
ping: cannot resolve www.letthemstare.com: Unknown host
Kfirs-MacBook-Pro:~ silis$ 

root@letthemstare:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

2. Magento Secure/Unsecure URLs were configured to http://letthemstare.com/
3. Hosting DNS - Domain was configured to letthemstare.com

Yet, every time I use letthemstare.com URL in my browser, it's being redirected to www.letthemstare.com (which is not reachable). 
I guess I have a mistake in my vhost configuration file but I fail to identify it.

Kindly help me to clear the unwanted redirection to www domain and also redirect all www URLs to the non-www domain (my if condition should do that but now I doubt everything).

Thanks and advance.

Comment: What happens when you `curl -v http://letthemstare.com/`?

Comment: From the server, I manage to connect to the website 

root@letthemstare:~# curl -v http://letthemstare.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.1.1...
* Connected to letthemstare.com (127.0.1.1) port 80 (#0) 

But from my Mac, hostname is not found in DNS Cache

Kfirs-MacBook-Pro:~ silis$ curl -v http://letthemstare.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve host: letthemstare.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: letthemstare.com
Kfirs-MacBook-Pro:~ silis$

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `A`-record for `www.letthemstare.com` is not defined in DNS.

Also, adding `letthemstare.com` to server's `/etc/hosts` is not necessary if your DNS zone is configured properly.